# node.js not runing properly on port 8080

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to run a simple http example using node.js installed on my server. I am using the following code:

```
var http = require('http');
var server  = http.createServer(function(req, res)
{
console.log(req, url)
res.writeHead({myinformation:'Welcome To Node.js'});
res.write('Hello world!');
res.end();
});

server.listen(8080);
```

this is saved into the file: example.js which I run through Putty using the following command:

```
$ node example.js
```

But the problem is when I open my browser and type: `http://myserverip:8080` the following error appears on Putty:

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: listen EACCES
    at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1020:19)
    at listen (net.js:1061:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1127:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/newusr/httpExample/example.js:10:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
```

I am using Win7 and I followed [this guide](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/open-a-port-in-windows-firewall), to open the communication for port 8080, but still it is not working.

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: Did you check another service is not already listening on 8080?

Comment: Switch `8080` to some other number.

Comment: Also `url` from the `console.log` call isn't defined.

Comment: Yes, I check if other services are using that port, but no. it is free. I also changed the port number, but others don't work as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The EACCES error code occurs when some other service is listening on another port. Try another port, or run as root as sometimes you need those privileges to bind to certain ports.

Also, I think `console.log(req, url)` should be `console.log(req.url)`.